# Installing Filemaker Server with Apache running

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, filemaker

I am relatively new to Filemaker Server. I just downloaded the demo to test it out and I got an error saying:

To install Filemaker Server, ports 80 and 443 must be available.

I currently have an apache web server running on the machine and I know I am using these ports so I am not surprised by the error.

What is the best way to go install FMS with a pre-existing apache server running?

Is there a way to change the ports Apache uses? Or should I go about this in a different way? Any help would be great!

P.S. I am on a late 2012 mac mini with OS X Yosemite running Server

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to change the port where Apache is running. By default, Apache sets the port to 80. You can change this in your Apache `httpd.conf` file. Usually, this file is located at `/etc/apache2` on a mac. Change the line in the file with the `Listen` directive to for example something like this:

```
Listen 81
```

Don't forget to also change the port forwarding settings of your router if your server should also be available outside of your network.

Reference to the Apache docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#listen